Error on include my own library in ROS service
I have coded my own library for some purposes and use it in a ROS service. After modifying the CMakeLists file I get the following error:

undefined reference to `decirHola()' collect2: error: ld returned 1
exit status

My folders:
/catkin_ws
 /newpackage
   /src
     new_service.cpp
     /include
       json_handler.h
       json_handler.cpp

json_handler.h:
#ifndef __JSON_HANDLER_H__
#define __JSON_HANDLER_H__

#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/istreamwrapper.h"
#include "rapidjson/ostreamwrapper.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/prettywriter.h"

#include "ros/ros.h"

using namespace std;

namespace JsonHandler {

    void decirHola(void);

}

#endif

json_handler.cpp:
#include "json_handler.h"

void DecirHola() {

    ROS_INFO("Hola Mundo");

}

in CMakeLists:
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  src/include
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
  src/include/json_handler.cpp
)

add_executable(json_handler_lib src/include/json_handler.cpp)
target_link_libraries(json_handler_lib ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

In new_service.cpp:
#include "include/json_handler.h"

And call:
JsonHandler::decirHola();

Any solution?
Regards
